# How to add a column default?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I created a Postgres DB which contains 5 tables. Then I realized that the column `student.student_id` lacks a column default to generate an *UUID*:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
     student_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     date_of_birth Date NOT NULL
)
```

Knowing that some tables are linked to the `student` table, how can I add to the function as column default for `student_id` so that the result will be:

```
     student_id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE student
ALTER COLUMN student_id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

Column defaults do not conflict with `FOREIGN KEY` references.